# Aging Formula in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I calculated aging of an event from its day of occurrence to today's date. It's working fine. But I want to stop aging after another event which will occur at a future date . How can I stop aging when the second event occurs.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are doing your current calculation as:

```
=TODAY()-first_event
```

where `first_event` is the cell containing the date of the event.

You probably want something similar to:

```
=MIN(second_event,TODAY())-first_event
```

If you need better accuracy than whole days, you can use `NOW()` instead of `TODAY()`.